# question on yui3 JS

Tags: javascript, yui, yui3

I have 2 different JS files: A.js and B.js. A.js looks something like this:

```
YUI.use('a few modules',function(Y) {
var Spinner=function(config) {
//invoke a constructor
}
Spinner.NAME='spinnerobject';
Spinner.ATTRS={
status:{
value:false
,readonly:true
,broadcast:2
}
};
Y.extend(Spinner,Y.Base, {
initializer: 
//many initializers here
, this.setstatus: function() {
//sets the status variable appropriately
}
});
});
```

B.js is this:

```
YUI.use('a few modules',function(Y) {
var button_yui2 = Y.YUI2.widget.Button( { initializing parameters for button}
);
button_yui2.on('change',function(e){
spinnerobject.setstatus(); // call made to a function in A.js
});
```

I'm not able to call the function setstatus from B.js. The function is not executed at all. Although no error is thrown. What might be the issue with this?

Answer (score 2):

there are a bunch of things that dont make sense with the code you posted.  where are you instantiating a spinnerobject?  i'll attempt to help based on what i think you're trying to do.

first off, you are never registering the spinner component with the system.  in a.js, you declare var spinner inside the YUI.use function.  That makes it impossible to access from outside that yui.use.  you either need to use a yui.add instead of yui.use or put Y.namespace('myNS').Spinner = Spinner; as the last line of a.js.  That will make your spinner component globally available as Y.myNS.Spinner.

next, initializer needs to be a function:

```
Y.extend(Spinner, Y.Base, {
    initializer: function(cfg) {
        // do your init stuff here
    }
});
```

and setstatus should just be a member of the prototype properties object passed to extend

```
Y.extend(Spinner, Y.Base, {
    initializer: function(cfg) {
        // do your init stuff here
    },

    setstatus: function() {
        // set status
    }
});
```

So now in b.js, you can initialize a new spinner object

```
YUI.use('a few modules',function(Y) {
    var button_yui2 = new Y.YUI2.widget.Button({initializing parameters for button}),
        spinnerobject = new Y.myNS.Spinner({/*config object*/});

    button_yui2.on('change',function(e){
        spinnerobject.setstatus(); // call made to a function in A.js
     });
});
```

hopefully this helps.  sorry if i didnt grok what you were trying to do.